# Get the size of an array from its type

Tags: c++, templates

I have a template parameter T which I know will be a

```
MyArray<Tbis, n>
```

Is there a way to get back the integer n so I can use it as a template parameter ?

Best regards,

Comment: Piotr: I have changed my question. Thanks for the hint.

Comment: Why did I get a -1 ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I understand the question correctly, you want to get the size of an array, and use as a template argument. For that, you can use [size()](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/array/size), since it is a constexpr.

Something like this :

```
#include <iostream>
#include <array>


typedef std::array< int, 72 > myArray;

template< int N = myArray().size() >
struct A
{
    void foo()
    {
        std::cout << N << std::endl;
    }
};

int main()
{
    A<> a;

    a.foo();
}
```

Comment: Thanks very much for your help. MyArray has a size() method like std::array. Therefore, I've been able to implement your idea changing size to a constexpr.

Comment: Why aren't you using std::array?

Comment: graham.reeds: I a building my own library. I don't want to use std::vector because of the way the standard library deals with allocators which change the type of objects. I also want portability of my code (bound checking is not portable for instance as there is no way to bound check the [] operator in debug mode in a portable way) across different plateforms. I would like to build something close to what is available here : http://www.bloomberglabs.com/basic-development-environment/about . For consistency, I have developped my own std::array.

Answer (score 1):

Is this what you're trying to do?

```
#include <iostream>
#include <array>

template <typename T, size_t N>
void f(std::array<T, N>& a)
{
    std::cout << N << '\n'; 
}

int main()
{
    std::array<int, 34> a;
    f(a);
}
```

Comment: Sweet. Fight template with template ;-). The idea will of course work as well with MyArray<T, n>.

Answer (score 0):

Yes. The member functions (on Visual Studio 2010 at least) `size()` and `max_size()` both return the number of items.

```
#include "stdafx.h"
#include <array>
#include <iostream>

template<class T>
int tuple_size(T t)
{
    return std::tuple_size<T>::value;
}

int main()
{ 
    std::array<int, 4> nums;
    std::cout << "size(): " << nums.size() << "\n";
    std::cout << "max_size(): " << nums.max_size() << "\n";
    std::cout << "tuple_size: " << tuple_size(nums)  << "\n";
}
```

Comment: Why is this -1? `size()` is a constexpr, and can be used as a template argument

Comment: I had also answered on the unedited question. Had I saw the edited version before I started VS and wrote the test to check my answer I would of used tuple_size also.

Comment: @BЈовић: `size()` is constexpr since C++11, not before.